# Should statics be used within C function?

Tags: c

I am wondering if C code would be better if static variables were used. Here is an example.

These are the settings initialized in `init(struct settings* )` and **never change**:

```
struct settings
{
    float vmin;
    float vmax;
    float v0;
};
```

Current `do_something()` implementation looks like:

```
float do_something(struct settings* set, const float* in, int n)
{
    float out = 0.0f;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        out += in[i] * set->v0 + in[i] * in[i] * set->vmin + in[i] * in[i] * in[i] * set->vmax + ...;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Would the following `static const` usage be more proper?

```
float do_something(struct settings* set, const float* in, int n)
{
    static const float V0 = set->v0; 
    static const float VMIN = set->vmin; 
    static const float VMAX = set->vmax; 

    float out = 0.0f;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        out += in[i] * V0 + in[i] * in[i] * VMIN + in[i] * in[i] * in[i] * VMAX + ...;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Would I gain anything?
The code runs on embedded DSP platforms with very tight resources.

Comment: Have you tried to use the last code? Did your compiler allow you to use `static const` there?

Comment: A static variable (const or not) is only initialized the first time the function is called. Subsequent calls do not run e.g. `V0 = ctx->v0;` again; the variable retains its original value through calls. Make sure this is what you want. (Essentially, this only is correct if `ctx->v0` never changes.) And yes, *if* that is the case you save a few cycles dereferencing and indexing `ctx`. Because it will only be done once during the program's lifetime.

Comment: You can't initialize `static` variables like this so the question doesn't make any sense. The code won't compile and that's that... Is it meant to say `ctx` or `set`? What is `ctx`? you don't use `set`...

Comment: Sorry, `ctx` is `set`, fixed it.

Comment: @Lundin But the code compiles (using GCC, `-std=gnu99`), moreover, there are no warnings reported.

Comment: No it doesn't. There are 8 errors reported in lax GNU99 mode and strictly conforming C17 mode both. https://godbolt.org/z/r7jTYG7xc I'm guessing you are using a C++ compiler or something...

Comment: The short answer is no. Don't use language features you don't understand, as you'll just wind up with very difficult-to-debug glitches like the ones your code above will definitely cause.

Comment: Sure... I'm not using the code I don't understand - I am asking about the code I don't understand. I'm using the code I do understand - version 1 of `do_something()` above...

Answer (score 1):

static loacal variables have to used with care.

1. They make the function not reentrant.
2. They prevent value between the function call - I saw many C programmers in the past thinking that they will be initialized at every function call. Using global scope objects is generally considered as a bad idea.
3. static storage duration variables cannot be initialized as in your second example, only constant expressions can be used.
4. No VLAs
5. Modularizing programs is almost impossible (same as with global variables).
6. It prevents the compiler from optimizing out the variables (as their state has to be saved). Many other optimizations are also affected (like automatic inlining, which is limited)

Comment: `static` local variables don't always "make the function not reentrant" - e.g. if they're never modified after initialization (which is what the asker is asking about) then it's not a problem for reentrancy at all.,

Answer (score -1):

> Would I gain anything?

For `static` local variables, the compiler has to put them somewhere, and "where" is the same place that it would've put them if they were global variables (e.g. in the executable's ".data" section or ".bss" section).

For your code, the definition of `ctx` isn't shown. The most likely assumption is that it's a global variable.

With this in mind; the use of `static` local variables in the second version of `do_something()` is mostly just creating a redundant copy of what you already had in the same area that it already was.

The only reasons (that I can think of) for that to be better than a waste of memory are:

1. You need to make sure that changing the contents of `ctx` doesn't effect the results for `do_something()`. Your first version of `do_something()` implies that this is not the case.
2. The compiler is so bad at optimizing code that the compiler should not be used (especially on platforms with very tight resources). Specifically, the compiler failed to optimize `ctx->v0` into a normal load despite the fact that it's global and both the location of the structure and the location/offset of the `v0` field within the structure are known at compile/link time.

Comment: "With this in mind; the use of static local variables in the second version of do_something() is mostly just creating a redundant copy" No because you can't initialize static storage duration variables to anything but constant expressions. So the code won't compile and most of your answer is therefore incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin: I would/have treated that as minor mistake in the way the asker composed their question, and not a relevant part of the "does using static help" question.

Comment: It's not a minor mistake, because the answer to the question "should statics be used within C function?" doesn't make any sense at all given the example code. The question can't really be answered in its current state.

Comment: @Lundin: The question's title doesn't accurately represent the question (it's not "should statics be used in general for any function", it's asking about a specific function). For the specific function; people frequently make mistakes when trying to create a "minimal and reproducible" example (e.g. forgetting to show the definition of `ctx`). Further, I'm not even convinced it's a "bug" given that `ctx` may be constant and that compilers for DSPs often don't strictly adhere to the C standard.

Comment: @Brendan `const` objexts are not constant expressions.  BTW static will most likely "waste: more memory as state of the `static` variables has to be prevented between the function calls and compiler can not optimize them out.

Comment: On a typical embedded systems, the CRT will need to initialize `.data` from flash upon program start-up. Which is only possible if the values to initialize with are located in flash to begin with - for that they need to be read-only. So the physical limitations of common embedded systems happen to correspond quite well with the "theoretical" limit of C only allowing constant expressions as initializers.

Comment: @0___________: How do you define "constant expression" (when strict adherence to the C standard may not apply)? I'd define it as "any expression that the compiler can reduce to constant" (which may include the expression `ctx->v0` if it's constant,).

Comment: If you look at C++ which allows initializers to be pretty much anything, as a result a conforming C++ CRT becomes a complete clusterf***, needing to address all the various complex initialization rules of that language. All the different types of initializer classifications have to be carried out in various orders in relation to each other etc. It's very unlikely that a DSP compiler vendor making a C compiler would want to implement all that complexity just in order to not adhere to the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin: Most compilers support both C and C++; so it's just as likely that complexity needed to support C++ anyway "leaks" into the implementation of C because the compiler developers didn't have even more complexity to prevent programmers from doing things in C that make sense.

Comment: No, you definitely don't want C++ functionality to "leak" into your CRT for C, because that comes with a significant performance loss. C++ programs take a whole lot longer to start than C programs due to the way C++ is designed. This would be especially troublesome for DSP programs where performance is very likely critical.

Comment: @Lundin: To minimize/reduce the startup costs in C++ you'd want the compiler to be able to figure out things like `ctx->v0` (if/where possible) at compile time instead. It's this "ability to figure out `ctx->v0` (if/where possible) at compile time" that may leak from C++ into C.

Comment: The thing is, the compiler can't go and make assumptions "you don't want to allocate this file scope variable". Which in turn mostly has to do with the compiler only seeing one translation unit at a time. As soon as a variable is allocated, all the rules regarding initialization apply. In C++ there's a tonne of them, and it also has intricate rules regarding initialization order.

Comment: @Lundin: Those "rules" are made out of butter (soft, malleable and easily melted away). A simple example is every single modern compiler (link-time optimization and link-time code generation breaking the ancient "failure to optimize" problems caused by horrendously antiquated "one translation at a time" implementation details).

Comment: Like it or not, this question is tagged C so it is about the behavior or C compilers. If the OP is interested in non-standard extensions, whether they are physically possible or not, they need to clarify that.